# how to make select element to adjust according to elements string length? (Angular2)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have an angular select element in my html:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign=" center">

    <div fxLayout="column">
      <md-select placeholder="My Select" name="select">
        <md-option *ngFor="let elem of elements" [value]="select.value">
          {{elem.textValue}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>

</div>
```

and some of my `textValue`'s are a bit longer than the select default size, so its going out of the element borders:

[image]

how can I make it to adjust to the text size?

Comment: what version of angular material are you using? material 2.0.0-beta.3 shows extra text as `...`. Additionally, you can always use a class and give it a width, see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Please post a valid plunker link.

Answer (score 1):

In material design, ***the contents do not set the size of elements***.

The elements have to be flexible and in perfect harmony and proportion with the rest of the layout elements and should be able to change texture, color, size and importance based on user focus/interaction.

> The fundamentals of light, surface, and movement are key to conveying how objects move, interact, and exist in space and in relation to each other. Realistic lighting shows seams, divides space, and indicates moving parts.

The content has to adjust and follow in a natural way.

As such, content does not set the size of an element, but has to look good in all element states, **even when clipped**.

Consider using

```
text-overflow:elipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

...on `<md-option>`s. If you don't like or disagree with the [md principles & guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/), don't use material design.
But if you use it, understand and respect its principles.

Other options include:

- shorten the message
- place some info above the select box or inside a tooltip so the user can access more information if they want to.